# Need help posting twice unique field and expecting error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, duplicates

I am writing a test that would check if correct exception and error message is thrown whenever someone tries to post the same unique client twice.
I need help figuring it out.

My code:

```
@Test
public void testDuplicatingKeys() throws Exception{

    CreateClient createClient = new CreateClient ();
    createClient.setBic(Bic.1111);
    createClient.setCif("cif");
    createClient.setLegalCode("legalCode");

    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/clients")
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(createClient))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated()).andReturn();

    MvcResult mvcResult1 = mockMvc.perform(post("/clients")
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(createClient))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated()).andReturn();
}
```

So the first time it performs a post request, it should post a client with this request body(`Bic.1111, "cif", "legalCode"`) and get a `isCreated` status. And eveything is ok. But for the second time it tries to post the same client with the same request body it should get an error(for now it is http-500 with an `ConstraintViolationException`) but somehow it still gets the `isCreated` status. How do I imitate posting two times same client and getting an error? Thanks

My `ClientController.java`:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/clients")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Client createBgwClient(@RequestBody CreateClient createClient) {
    Client Client =
            new Client(
                    createClient.getBic(),
                    createClient.getCif(),
                    createClient.getLegalCode()
            );

    return clientRepository.save(client);
}
```

Comment: i suspect you are trying to write unit test case can you post code from controller service, repository?

Comment: @psi why do you need that? I just need to figure out a way to post the same request body twice and get an error the second time.

Comment: The problem is in your controller not in this unit test. This test does what you expect , it sends request two times. If it fetches  **isCreated** then your controller behave wrongly

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak added controller code

Comment: What is mockMvc in your code ? Does it send real http request ?

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak it's a Spring MVC test support. As I understand it doesn't

Comment: `Client Client = ` that even compiles?

Comment: You would have to show us how you defined (and where) your constains.

Comment: and IMHO, that should be tested in repository test not on mvc layer. Here you would only use mocks to actualy test code in controller layer.

Comment: If it doesn't send real http call then it works as expected , create real server and send real http request if you want to prove correctness of your service

Comment: Since this is unit test you should test it independently not all combined

Comment: I am facing the same issue today, I suspect it's because the of the MockMVC, which instead of committing the requests to the database keeps stuff in memory and doesn't see that it is supposed to fail. You can see that your code works if you try to read from the database as in that case it will try to write before reading and fails.
Although the code works as expected in prod in doesn't in the test. If I find more info I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintViolationException is database exception so you have constraint on those variables. For example primarkey, uniqueconstraint etc..
You can check the response message is similar to andExpect part of mockMVC.
If you don't handle the error message, then it is different case. Maybe you can check @ControllerAdvice.
If you send table entity we can check it if you are creating with hibernate.
If possible you can send the constraints on the table.